# MW versus MWh is one total capacity and the other maximum output?

Tags: microgrid, battery-storage

I still don't completely understand MW versus MWh, I have been working on a Wikipedia article for Tesla's "megapack" battery which are measured in both.

I assumed one was an indication of how much power it could dump at any one time and the other the total amount of power stored.

For example one the applications for a backup powersupply for trainlines where it needs to dump a huge amount of power of a relatively short amount of time so as to get trains to platforms during a blackout.

So I assumed 7MWh was the amount it could pump out in any one time and 4.2MW was the amount of power it stored in total, am I wrong?

I want to put a simple explanation in the article.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesla_Megapack#Examples_of_installed_Powerpack_and_Megapack_systems

Comment: Other way round. It can pump out 4.2MW, (energy rate = power) and do so for over 1.5 hours (giving total energy 7 MWh)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How convert kWh to W](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/356336/how-convert-kwh-to-w)

Comment: @BrianDrummond that should be an answer, although it's short it's entirely corret

Comment: I still don't understand, I am generally quite technical and am struggling with this, I want to be able to explain it in the article in a way anyone could understand

Comment: You should google "power vs energy".  MW is power and MWH is energy.  Energy is power over time.  I.e. 1 MW of power running for 1 hour takes 1 MWh of energy.

Comment: I would caution against putting an explanation in the wiki article until you really understand it. I've read it, and I'm not sure it really needs it. It's one of those things where if you need to know, then you know, and if you don't, it doesn't matter. You might sort out the formatting of the table in that article.

Comment: There's no need to explain anything extra in that Wiki article since it is the most basic knowledge as far as that topic is concerned. It isn't specialized, niche knowledge that needs to be specifically elaborated on in-situ.

Comment: Energy (Joules or MW-h) is like how much money you have in your bank account, power (Watts or MW) is your hourly wage or daily withdrawl limit. It is simple. You're overthinking something somewhere. Do you know the difference between power and energy? Do you know how a Watt and Joule are related to each other? If you don't there is no point going any farther until you do.

Answer (score 1):

MW is power, the rate of doing work. MWh is energy, how much total work can be done.

To use a water analogy, MWh is the size of the water tank, MW is the size of the pipe going to the tank.

Generally, larger tanks will have larger pipes, but that's not always the case. A small tank with a large pipe can fill and empty fast. This is what you get with high power LiPos, that fly drones for only 5 minutes. A big tank with a small pipe will take a long time to fill or empty.

If you want to shift a train to a platform, then you need a lot of power, high MW rating, but not for long, small MWh rating.

Answer (score 0):

Say you were pulling a wagon up a hill using your battery.  It takes energy to do this (the unit for energy is a joule).  So it takes some number of joules to get to the top.  A watt is a joule per second so a battery capable of 4.2 MW means that it can produce joules at rate twice that of one with a 2.1 MW rating.  Both can get you up the hill, but one can get the job done twice as fast.

Your 7MWH rating means that the battery will be out of energy after the product of multiplying the power times the time is running equals 7MWH.  In your example it would theoretically run out of energy after running 1 hour, 40 minutes (7/4.2).  So 7 MWH is how much energy (also termed "capacity") the battery contains.  MWH another unit of energy and can be directly converted back to joules.

In summary, two batteries with the same MWH rating will go the same distance up the hill before running out of juice.  One with a higher MW rating will get you there faster.

Answer (score 0):

MW is MegaWatt and MWh is MegaWatt hour.

MW is a unit of power and MWh is a unit of energy.

Taking the Brisbane example...

2.2 MWh is the installed battery capacity which can energise the installed 1.1 MW load for 2 hours.